# SQL GROUP BY - grouping null and zero together

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, eloquent

I'm using laravel's eloquent and i'm trying the following:

```
$vouchers = $vouchers->groupBy(
            'content_type_voucher.crsRel','content_type_voucher.dbdRel');
```

The problem is the database I am using (and cannot update) uses null and zero in the same meaning therefore when I'm using groupBy I want the entries with zero or null values to be grouped together.

any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: use `COALESCE(column,0)` in the subquery, then `GROUP BY` based on that

Comment: Can you use `IFNULL([your_column_name], 0)` in your query?

Comment: @DanielTsvetkov thumbs up upvote xD